# Shutting down Linux server on first Wednesday of every month

Tags: linux, crontab

I have written a crontab entry as:

```
00 19 1-7 * 3 /sbin/init 0
```

It should turn my linux server off on the first Wednesday of every month. Unfortunately the server went off on today (Thursday). Can anyone please tell me why it happened like this and please tell me how I can fix it.

Answer (score 6):

From [crontab(5)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5):

```
   Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields --
   day of month, and day of week.  If  both  fields  are  restricted  (ie,
   aren't  *),  the command will be run when either field matches the cur-
   rent time.
```

This means your *crontab* entry won't work as expected. The command will run every day from to 1st to the 7th every month, plus every Wednesday.

Because of the above, *cron* alone won't be able to decide whether it's the first Wednesday of the month or not. However, you can check for one condition using *cron* and check for the other with *test* and *date*:

```
00 19 1-7 * * [ $(/usr/bin/date +\%w) = 3 ] && /sbin/init 0
```

How it works:

- The command will be executed every day from the 1st to the 7th day of the month.
- `$(/usr/bin/date +\%w)` returns the weekday.
- `[ ... = 3 ] &&` checks if that weekday is Wednesday (3).
- If it is, `/sbin/init 0` gets executed.

Note that you have to escape the percent sign, as it is special to *cron*.

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thank you very much for the reply. Could you please suggest me a correct way of shutting down the server at 1900 hours on first Wednesday of every month?

Comment: I was going to post this almost an hour ago, but crontab didn't behave like I thought it would. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Done. So a percent sign in the crontab indicates a comment. You live, you learn...

Comment: Thank you very much Dennis. Much appreciated. I will test it and update you.